# ALAsset Does every asset belong to an Event?

Tags: alassetslibrary, alasset

I am doing a project that involves ALassets. I know that from iphoto every picture in the phone belongs to an event. Events seem to be like folders. What is not clear to me is, if you synch your phone to a PC and not a mac, does every asset still belong to an event?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

The AssetLibrary has so called groups. The groups contain the assets. There are groups of the following types:

```
enum {
    ALAssetsGroupLibrary        = (1 << 0),         // The Library group that includes all assets.
    ALAssetsGroupAlbum          = (1 << 1),         // All the albums synced from iTunes or created on the device.
    ALAssetsGroupEvent          = (1 << 2),         // All the events synced from iTunes.
    ALAssetsGroupFaces          = (1 << 3),         // All the faces albums synced from iTunes.
    ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos    = (1 << 4),         // The Saved Photos album.
    ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream    = (1 << 5),         // The PhotoStream album.
    ALAssetsGroupAll            = 0xFFFFFFFF,       // The same as ORing together all the available group types, 
                                                    // with the exception that ALAssetsGroupLibrary is not included.
};
```

An asset is only part of an event, if it has been synced by iTunes or created by the Camera Connection Kit. Photos taken on the device are always part of the ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos (Camera Roll) and can additionally be assigned to user created album.